# PHP convert comma separated string with square brackets into array

Tags: php, arrays

My string looks like:

[10,20,30]

I want to convert it to an array.

I've tried:

```
$myArray=explode(",",$myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

But this is returning:

```
Array ( [0] => [10 [1] => 20 [2] => 30] )
```

I need to get rid of the opening/closing brackets.

Can someone help?

Comment: What did you try to get rid of the opening/closing brackets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array of numbers in that particular format is valid JSON, so you can use [PHP’s built-in function](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$myArray = json_decode($myString);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can remove the square brackets first with str_replace function. Then you can simply do the rest. This will work I think.

```
$inputString = "[10,20,30]";
$processString = str_replace(array('[',']') ,'' , $inputString);
$outputArray = explode(',' , $processString);
var_dump($outputArray);

//output:
//array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(2) "20" [2]=> string(2) "30" }
```